# Canyouseeme.org vs telnet <ip> <port>

Tags: telnet

When a visitor visits the site canyouseeme.org and type in a port number, let's say 80 for example, (IP is already detected by canyouseeme), would that be equivalent to do the following telnet:

```
telnet <ip-detected-and-reported-by-canyouseeme> 80
```

In my case, canyouseeme can see the service on my IP on the specified port, but telnet says that the connection is refused and unable to connect.

Why the difference?

Comment: if you're behind a NAT Router, you can't access that external ip internally.  Try going to a computer at another location and running that telnet ip 80

Comment: and try with nmap too.. I think this is the line, you may not need -P0.  C:\>nmap -P0 -p80 ip